# Is There an Easy Way to Convert Python/Pygame code into C#?

Tags: c#, python

I am working on a game, sort of like this and I want to convert it to C#, as it is currently written in Python. The reason of this is because I can add features more easily and with less writing in C#, and I do NOT want to write it all again, with all of the glitches and testing having to be redone. Is there any program of internet service that can do so, for free? I don't have extra money to spend on this, which is just for fun. Thanks for all feedback, edits, and suggestions!

Edit: I use Wing IDE 4.1 for my Python coding and the Unity Version of MonoDevelop for C#.

Comment: I don't believe there's an exact PyGame equivalent for C#, so you'll have to build your code off another library. But since you've already solved all your bugs/glitches, you'll know the solution as soon as you encounter it, so it won't be as bad.

Comment: @RobertRouhani Thanks! That's true, and I may try to use Unity for the graphics instead of using PyGame. Most of the bugs took lots of tries to fix, so hopefully it will take less time this time around :P

Comment: @PythonInProgress: will you be CSharpInProgress from now on?

Comment: The answer is No, not an easy way. Some tools exist: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-python/

And you might be able to use IronPython and actually reuse your Python code from C#. (Just guessing here, but maybe its the same as Java & Groovy)

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Maybe, but probably not. I think I'll use the 'company' name I have from now on.

Comment: @sm4 can you change that comment into an answer? If there is no more answers, the comment will be accepted as the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, "translating" code from one language to another (or to run on one system or another) is called a [**port**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) (note interesting relation or *port* to *portable*).

Ports take a lot of work, and although there are many tools out to "help" you perform the task of porting, [it's largely going to be a manual process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358016/convert-python-to-c-sharp).

If you want to program in C#, a good thing to do is just re-implement your program in C#, using your Python code base as a reference.  Along the way you could find and make some improvements.

Comment: thanks @bobobobo that helps a lot more than you would think.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free online tool to convert Python to C#.

https://pythoncsharp.com

This is an automated conversion, so will not be perfect but will bring across the control of flow and general structure of a script.